# How to rebuild select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I've modified select2 sources (`core.js`)

What should I do to rebuild the files in `dist` directory :

- `select2.full.js`
- `select2.js`
- etc

Comment: grunt compile? https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L344 . Or simply grunt - it will run default task with compile, test and minify

Comment: This is it, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally such common tasks always get built by a `build` task or in this case `compile` task (as answered in comments).


Or simply doing `gulp` or `grunt` (in this case) will always run your `default` task, if defined which is a good practice to.

So you can do `grunt compile` or simply `grunt` (as answered in comments) most of the time.